# Java: Run/Open/Edit any file

Tags: java

Using Java program I need to run/open/edit any file. This should have similar effect of double clicking file in File Explorer and OS will execute file if it an executable OR open/edit it in it's respective registered program.

I have tried the Runtime.exec() method (See down there) but that method only runs executable files. I need mine to run any file. This includes text files, audio files, pictures, anything.

I have tried the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("README.txt");
```

Comment: Also, remember, `*.txt` is not an executable file format that the OS can "run".  Depending on the OS, there are any number of ways you might achieve this, but that will make your code quite messy and difficult to mainatin...

Comment: No need to down vote this question. This is a legit question.

Comment: (You can only use `exec` on executable files.  For other files you must appropriately identify the program needed to display them.  Eg, a text file needs something like `notepad.exe`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you consider trying to use [the `java.awt.Desktop` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)?

For example...

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        if (Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.EDIT)) {
            Desktop.getDesktop().edit(new File("Readme.txt"));
        }
        // or...
        if (Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("Readme.txt"));
        }
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will attempt to open/edit the file in the OS specified editor for the given file

Comment: You may additionally want to add a check to see if that respective action is supported

Comment: @GladwinB What, type more!!? ;)

Comment: First make a check if file is executable and if not only then use open/edit.

Comment: Depends on what needs to be achieved and this could go into totally tangent discussion so let's not discuss further. Note I already up voted your solution :-)

Comment: @GladwinB That depends and is generally OS specific, besides, open can actually execute run executable commands.  At this point, without further context, I'm not sure it's actually relievent

Comment: From the very brief test i did it seemed this has done the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : That's great, I have not used this API so was going safer route. How does it behaves when file does not have any registered program?

Comment: @GladwinB I think that's where the `IOException` comes in :P